# Heroku: R14 Memory errors when using the ephemeral file system (golang buildpack)

Tags: heroku, go

I have a Go-lang application on Heroku which downloads a large no.(2000s) of small files(200KB) from S3, processes it and then uploads a zipped archive of all those files back to S3.

I'm using [this build pack](https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go/), and all the processing happens under the `/tmp` folder.

The zipped archive can be 400-500MB in size, plus additional space is occupied by the downloaded files. When the processing is underway, I get the Error r14 Memory Quota exceeded error.

My question is - does writing to the ephemeral file system contribute to the Memory Quota limit ? or is that just limited to the RAM.

Thank you.

Comment: Heroku support said that the file system does not contribute to the Memory Quota

Comment: You could post your comment as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Maybe you are loading entire file to the memory. Use streams to avoid that.